# FTP.retrbinary() doesn't work for PDF file, only some text is copied into the new file

Tags: python, file, ftp, copy, ftplib

The files are getting created, but the PDF files have much less text just than the original PDFs, only the initial text.

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(host='host', port=port)
ftp.login(user='uname', passwd=*****, acct='')
for file in ftp.nlst(dir_name):
    with open(local_file, "wb") as f:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file, f.write)
ftp.quit()
```